# How to maintain .ipynb running in the background with VSCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I have installed `jupyter-related` plugins in VS Code. While I close the VS Code, the GPU memory is cleared. I can't use jupyter like the traditional method in the browser.

I changed the jupyter to remote with localhost: port in VS Code, the `Jupyter: Server Remote` displayed in the button of VS Code GUI.

**Steps:**

1. The remote jupyter notebook is running in the tmux with & bash option.
2. Add port forward in VSCode.(maybe unnecessary)
3. `Ctrl + Shift + P` and search "Jupyter: Specify Jupyter Server for connections".
4. Add URL with the token.
5. Run a ipynb file and `nvidia-smi` to see the usage of GPU.
6. Close the VSCode, the GPU memory is clear.

[image: State of Jupyter Server:Remote]

Comment: Unfortunately this is a known issue, no solution currently. Please vote on this issue:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/3998

Answer (score 0):

When you use remote mode, the code runs in the server instead of the local computer.

Please operate again according to the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks#_connect-to-a-remote-jupyter-server).

1. Select the **Jupyter Server: local** button in the global Status bar or run the **Jupyter: Specify local or remote Jupyter server for connections** command from the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P).
2. When prompted to **Pick how to connect to Jupyter**, select Existing: **Specify the URI of an existing server**.
3. When **prompted to Enter the URI** of a Jupyter server, provide the server's URI (hostname) with the authentication token included with a URL parameter. (If you start the server in the VS Code terminal with an authentication token enabled, the URL with the token typically appears in the terminal output from where you can copy it.) Alternatively, you can specify a username and password after providing the URI

Comment: I expected ipynb still run in the background after closing VS Code, but it doesn't. Even if I tried to start `jupyter notebook &` in tmux by myself, it still doesn't work.

Comment: @cccrick Add `"shutdownAction": "none"` in `devcontainer.json`.  You can refer to [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/devcontainerjson-reference) for more information.